# When adding an object i need the user to be taken authomaticaly

Tags: django

I need when saving an object on the DB to be inserted authomaticaly the user of the peer. I need this, just because if i let the models as they were with Foreign key, basically the user could change it;s user so when saving the object we could have different users etc.

Therefore i changed in my models from `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)` to

```
user = models.CharField(max_length=80,blank=True, null=True)
```

and put these lines:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if not obj:
        user = request.user
        form.base_fields['user'].initial = user.user
        form.base_fields['email'].initial = user.email
    return form

AttributeError at /admin/parcare/parking/add/
'User' object has no attribute 'user'
```

What am I doing wrong?

class Parking(models.Model):

```
PARKING_PLOT = (
    ('P1', 'Parking #1'),('P2', 'Parking #2'), ('P3', 'Parking #3'),
    ('P4', 'Parking #4'),('P5', 'Parking #5'), ('P6', 'Parking #6'),
    ('P7', 'Parking #7'),('P8', 'Parking #8'), ('P9', 'Parking #9'),
    ('P10', 'Parking #10'),('P11', 'Parking #11'), ('P12', 'Parking #12'),
    ('P13', 'Parking #13'),('P14', 'Parking #14'), ('P15', 'Parking #15')

)
# user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
user = models.CharField(max_length=80,blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
parking_on = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date you want to come in the office.',)
parking_off = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date when you leave')
numar_masina = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="IF77WXV", blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please insert your license plate number')
location = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="P1", null=True, choices=PARKING_PLOT,help_text='Please select the desired parking plot.')
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue it with you trying to use `user.user`. User class from `request.user` doesn't have such attribute. Instead, you could use `user.username` and save that to the form:

`form.base_fields['user'].initial = user.username`.

User model reference can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/).